# Observable for a callback in Rx

Tags: c#, callback, system.reactive, observable

I'm looking for an elegant way to create an `Observable` from a plain callback delegate with Rx, something similar to [`Observable.FromEventPattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromeventpattern%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)?

Say, I'm wrapping Win32 [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API which calls back the `EnumWindowsProc` I provide.

I know I could create a temporary C# event adapter for this callback and pass it `FromEventPattern`. Also, I could probably implement `IObservable` manually, so it would call `IObserver.OnNext` from my `EnumWindowsProc` callback.

Is the there an existing pattern for wrapping a callback in Rx that I'm missing?

Comment: Or you could simply use a `Subject` and call `OnNext` on it in the callback.

Comment: @Dirk, interesting, thanks. So, `Subject.OnNext` then `Subject.OnComplete` when there is no more items?

Comment: Yes, Subject implements both `IObservable` and `IObserver`. Call OnNext/OnError/OnCompleted to issue those commands to the subscribers of the Subject. They server as kind of a gateway from non-Rx to Rx code.

Comment: @Dirk, thanks and maybe you should post it as an answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a [`Subject<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229173%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) which can be used to move from the imperative programming world into the functional world of Rx.

`Subject<T>` implements both `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>`, so you can call its `OnNext`, `OnError` and `OnCompleted` methods and the subscribers will be notified.

If you want to expose the `Subject<T>` as a property then you should do so using `.AsObservable()` as this hides the fact that the `IObservable<T>` is in fact a `Subject<T>`. It makes things such as `((Subject<string>) obj.Event).OnNext("Foo")` impossible.

Comment: This probably is the way to go. I'd just like to see what others may say, before accepting it.

Comment: @avo It's certainly an easy solution, but some people dislike using Subject as this is one of the few non-functional things in Rx. I think it has some good uses, but if there is another way - such as FromEventPattern - then I'd use that instead.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that callbacks like the one used in `EnumWindows` are subtly different than Rx.  Specifically, the callback can communicate back to the caller through its return value.  Rx observers cannot do this.  Also, callbacks can receive multiple parameters, but Rx observers receive a single value.  So you need to wrap the multiple parameters into a single object.

With that in mind, an alternative to using a `Subject` is to use `Observable.Create`.  This way you only register the callback when there is actually an observer and you unregister it if that observer unsubscribes.

For the synchronous API you've used an example, you might do something like this.  Note in this example there is not actually a way to unregister the callback mid-stream since it all happens synchronously before we can ever return the unsubscribe disposable.

```
public static IObservable<Foo> WrapFooApi(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    return Observable.Create<Foo>(observer =>
    {
        FooApi.enumerate(arg1, arg2, e =>
        {
            observer.OnNext(new Foo(e));
            return true;
        });

        // In your case, FooApi.enumerate is actually synchronous
        // so when we get to this line of code, we know
        // the stream is complete.
        observer.OnCompleted();
        return Disposable.Empty;
    });
}

// Usage
WrapFooApi("a", "b").Take(1).Subscribe(...); // only takes first item
```

We can fix the problem with being unable to stop early by introducing a little asynchronicity, which will give the observer time to get a disposable that it can dispose of to notify you.  We can use `CreateAsync` to get a `CancellationToken` that will cancel when the observer unsubscribes.  And we can run the `FooApi` code inside `Task.Run`:

```
public static IObservable<Foo> WrapFooApi(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    return Observable.CreateAsync<Foo>(async (observer, ct) =>
    {
        await Task.Run(() => FooApi.register_callback(arg1, arg2, e =>
        {
            observer.OnNext(e);

            // Returning false will stop the enumeration
            return !ct.IsCancellationRequested;
        }));
        observer.OnCompleted();
    });
}
```

In a more traditional asynchronous callback API, where you register at some point and unregister at some other point, you might have something more like this:

```
public static IObservable<Foo> WrapFooApi(string args)
{
    return Observable.Create<Foo>(observer =>
    {
        FooToken token = default(FooToken);
        var unsubscribe = Disposable.Create(() => FooApi.Unregister(token));
        token = FooApi.Register(args, e =>
        {
            observer.OnNext(new Foo(e));
        });

        return unsubscribe;
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think in this particular case you can use any async APIs to do this - the EnumWindows callback is invoked synchronously from the caller (i.e. imagine the EnumWindows API just uses a for loop and calls the callback for each item)